# My gold badge allowed me to instantly close a question despite the tag being edited out beforehand

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, privileges, dupehammer

I have a gold badge for the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag on Stack Overflow. This allows me to instantly close questions tagged with this.

I just voted to close this question: [How to get img dimensions from file object](//stackoverflow.com/questions/26337625/how-to-get-img-dimensions-from-file-object) and it instantly closed because the original question was tagged with CSS. This tag, however, had been [edited out](//stackoverflow.com/posts/26337625/revisions) before I voted to close it. Is this behaviour desired?

[image: Question Revision History]

---

#### Update

Just thought I'd mention that at the time I posted this question I only had the CSS Gold Tag Badge. I do now have the jQuery Gold Tag Badge as well, but that wasn't in play here at the time.

Comment: It would be nice to have a hammer warning/icon when I am voting to close it. I prefer to know what a button does when I click it :)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: you mean you are not actually taking care of how you use your close votes when you can hide among 4 other voters? Tut tut!

Comment: @martijnpieters - of course I take care but sometimes having a group to decide is better. Having a gold badge doesn't make me all-knowing and, yes I do admit, I make mistakes. Other than that, a button should tell you the result not hide a surprise :)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: the point I'm trying to make is that it shouldn't matter how you vote. You can always *retract* your close vote or vote to reopen if you were wrong, by the way. You do want to lose that group mentality, never close a post just because others voted to do so.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd your request is at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231625/147247

Comment: @MartijnPieters sometimes it's useful to say "I know this needs to be closed", other times it's useful to say "I think this should be closed what do you think?"... being a subject matter expert doesn't mean you should never feel the need to include others potentially differing opinions.

Comment: @Jason: then make a comment, and not a vote! Don't assume the other voters won't act like lemmings and blindly follow the leader over the cliff.

Comment: @Jason: and be flexible. You also have one insta-reopen vote. If there are people that disagree with the closure, you can discuss and easily reopen again too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough and I don't have a problem with that, but it seems like it might be desirable to increase the nuance with which you can respond.  A comment could easily be drowned or ignored, a close vote much less so... the fact that someone *else* might blindly follow is a concern, but regardless could feel like the appropriate level of response, more so than a comment and less so than a unilateral close.  Note, I don't own a gold badge in any tags, so I don't have to worry about this myself.

Comment: @Jason: I hold 8, and like moderators I learned the value of standing behind my votes, and at the same time being flexible and be quick to reopen if I was wrong. So far I have not found a need for anything else.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Would a flag perhaps be better than a comment?  If the badge-holder thinks a post should probably be closed, but doesn't have the expertise to know for certain, a comment would be unlikely to draw moderators' attention to the issue.

Comment: @supercat: no, because once you have earned the privilege to vote to close, you can no longer flag to close.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Perhaps *that's* the fundamental problem; the fact that someone has the authority to close-hammer a post directly doesn't imply that the person will know whether every post that seems like it should *probably* be closed, actually should be closed.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

That's correct and *by design*. Only the tags in the *initial revision* count for the dupe hammer.

Normally that is meant to prevent you from *adding* tags just to be able to use your hammer. Here it worked the other way; the OP made a mistake in adding the CSS tag, but because the initial revision had that tag your dupe hammer counts.

I think that's fine; no one should be able to *prevent* a dupe hammer from applying by quickly removing tags, either.

Comment: I see, that makes sense - I hadn't considered a possible abuse situation.

Comment: So if the first edit to a post adds/removes a tag, it's okay and your gold badge works, but subsequent edits have it "turned off"?

Comment: Sometimes I've noticed a problem with this behaviour. When somebody instead of putting a (for example) `python` tag uses the specific version tag (e.g. `python-2.x`) *without* putting also the main tag. In this case the number of possible dupe hammers suddenly becomes *much* smaller. And most of the time the question is actually version agnostic and it's only the OP that is using a specific version, but both the contents of the question and answer don't depend on the specific version used.

Comment: @TylerH: I may have misunderstood your comment; the initial revision is what the OP posted (plus grace period edits), so *no edits* can add or remove a tag.

Comment: @Bakuriu: yes, in which case the normal closing procedures apply. It doesn't actually happen all that often, and the dupe hammer is a great convenience but it is not like we cannot get a dupe closed anyway without it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters From my personal experience it happens much more often than tags edited out afterwards. You may not notice because you do have some version-specific gold tags and so, you are able to use the hammer even in those situations.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Bakuriu: [tag:python-2.7] has less than 7% the volume of the [tag:python] tag, [tag:python-3.x] about 4%, after which the numbers are *minute*, so really, this isn't that big a problem. That's the thing with dupe hammers; they are pretty much handed out in response to actual tag traffic. The 2.7 tag will have a second gold badge holder in a month or so, at the current rate. 3.x already has 2 gold badge holders.

Comment: @Bakuriu: then there are the 'type' gold badges; I have [tag:list], [tag:dictionary] and [tag:string] hammers, perhaps those are helping me close stuff more often than the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] hammers.

Comment: Does this "prevention" need to exist at all? Do we really have users with gold C# badges who we imagine would say "aha, this Java question is a duplicate of that other Java question, but I can't wield my hammer unless I re-tag it as C# first"? That doesn't sound like something I would worry about. Surely it'd be more common to *correctly* re-tag something, and then incidentally hammer it closed.

Comment: @amalloy: I do think so; we don't want controversial posts being retagged 6 months after just so someone can dupe-hammer or reopen it *again*.

Comment: If people earn enough trust to close questions with a single vote, shouldn't we also be able to trust them to not abuse the tagging system to apply those powers in evil ways?

Comment: @RetoKoradi: we trust them *in their field of expertise*. That's quite narrow. Allowing for arbitrary tag edits would suddenly allow that trust to be expanded to every single post.

Comment: I understand the reasoning. Similar to @amalloy above, I'm just not sure if it's likely to happen. Most gold tag badge holders probably have 20k+ rep, which comes along with various privileges that put a lot of trust in them. If we expect them to deliberately make lame moves like this, I would have concerns about them having a lot of their other privileges.

Comment: The cool thing about using gold badges for this, @Reto, is that it's not a fixed trust level. When you hit 3K, the system trusts you to vote to close - no amount of participation earns you *more* trust in that area. But there are currently 300+ *different* gold tag badges folks have earned on SO, and many more that could *potentially* be earned - and each one adds to the trust the system grants you.

Answer (score 24):

The ability for gold tag badge holders to close as a duplicate with a single vote is based on the **original** tags the question had.

This is to prevent you adding a tag and then closing the question.

It does result in anomalies like this one though.

Comment: The more direct way might be to just check if the tag was added by the close voter himself and if so, disregard the dupe hammer if existing.

Comment: Such a restriction would be trivial to work around, @Trilarion. If we were to go that route, we might as well save a little bit of database load and just pop up a message box asking folks nicely to not abuse it.

Answer (score 4):

[Martijn Pieters's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274354/839601) makes sense, but I think that in this particular case, a warning saying

> The question was edited since you entered the page, this is the new version, do you still want to vote that way?

could improve the voting relevance (while still allowing you to use your badge color according to the original version).

Comment: Actually, that would seem like a good idea any time someone clicks "close" or "downvote" next to a displayed post which doesn't match the current version.  One is supposed to be able to retract votes if a post is edited after the votes are given, but if the vote is posted *after* the post was edited (but before the edit was displayed) the user should still be able to retract the vote whether or not they notice it immediately [and they may not notice it immediately if the screen seems to refresh simply in response to the vote click].

Comment: Most folks already get notified if an edit is made while they're viewing the page (assuming websockets work). In all cases, you should be voting based on whether you think the post needs to be closed, not whether or not you think your vote will be binding - for all you know, by the time that vote is cast there are 4 others...

Answer (score 3):

As a suggestion, could the rule be changed from:

```
if ( match(orig_tags,'css') ) { /*...*/ }
```

to:

```
if ( match(orig_tags,'css') && match(current_tags,'css') { /*...*/ }
```

So that the abuse case is handled, but also this case and if a gold member wished to re-add a tag in order to close the question, they could and thus have the original functionality?

Don
have a great day

Comment: That would make it so any gold member of any tag can close any question they wanted.

Comment: Only if the tag was in the original question defined.