# Dupehammer for user in [tag] doesn't work if [tag] was added later

Tags: support, tags, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I have gold badge in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) so got all mighty close-as-dup hammer for quetsions tagged by [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

But if a question was edited to add this tag later then dupehammer stops working. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573719/how-do-i-shuffle-a-string-in-unity-c-sharp).

Is it a bug, or by design? It latter, I'd check whether or not the tag was added by the user or by somebody else.

Comment: That's not a bug but [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. Many dupes too.

Comment: Opposite ase would be this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274353/my-gold-badge-allowed-me-to-instantly-close-a-question-despite-the-tag-being-edi

Comment: Does anyone have a gold badge in [dupehammer] to close this?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I know you are joking, but nobody even has a silver badge yet. Shog9 is fairly close (353), and Martijn is the only other with even a bronze badge. Actually, on a more serious note, are there dupe hammers on meta? It would be ironic to use a dupe hammer on [dupehammer].

Comment: Marking as a dup with the question already marked and closed as a dup. Yay!

Answer (score 3):

This is to prevent you from adding the tag, then hammering the question.

But it doesn't discriminate.  If the user adds the tag, you also can't hammer.  Hard to say if that's an intended effect.

Comment: That is the intended behavior. The dupehammer only looks at the tags on the original revision. Everything else is simply ignored. It should be noted that the OP *can* edit the tags within the 5-minute grace period and change them, which would affect the dupehammer abilities.

Comment: I understand avoiding the situation when I could add the tag, close the question and then remove the tag. But when another user added the tag I think it should work as usually. (I don't talk about a collusion)